# Where to override oninit function of page

Tags: asp.net

In an ASP.NET web forms application, if I want to override the onInit function of the Page class, where do I write this code.

In one of my web forms, I wrote this code

```
    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        ViewStateUserKey = Session.SessionID;
        base.OnInit(e);
    }
```

The problem is that, when I run my appliation in debug mode I see that this function is not being called for each and every page.

So definitely I have made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: You have written this in one of your webforms so how will i work for every page, to make it work for every page you need to make your own base page and make your page inherit from that.

Comment: Please try googling, still some links for you http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/webforms/article.php/c11939/ASPNET-Tip-Create-a-BasePage-Class-for-All-Pages-to-Share.htm, http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/041305-1.aspx